# How to parent's child ul?

Tags: javascript, html-lists, parent-child

I need to get parent li of clicked on span and then show child ul of that li

```
 <ul id="menu">
    <div>
     <li class="reveal">
       <a href="##">!!!!!!!!!!!!</a>
       <span class="arrow_open">↓</span><br/> <!-- clicking this one -->
       <ul> <!-- display this one -->
        <li>a</li>
        <li>b</li>
        <li>c</li>
       </ul>
     </li>
   </div>
</ul>
```

And my code.

```
$(function () {
    $(this).parent("li").child("ul").slideToggle();
});
```

Comment: That looks like it should work. What's the problem?

Comment: That `div` within the `ul` is invalid markup.

Answer (score 2):

You have to set a click handler on the span, like so

```
$(function () {
    $('#menu .reveal span').on('click', function(){
        $(this).parent().find("ul").slideToggle();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Put this in your ready function:

```
$(".reveal span").click(function () {
    $(this).parent("li").children("ul").slideToggle();
});
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jeffman/BWJzJ/ Try it out.

Answer (score 0):

This should be faster to use this code but you have to set your sub-menu just after your link (like in your example):

```
$(function () {
    $('#menu .reveal .arrow_open').on('click', function(){
        $(this).next().slideToggle();
    });
});
```